# background-image desde javascript no funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs-scope

Tengo esta función usando angularjs que abre un modal para editar datos

```
$scope.Editar = function ($obj){
    $scope.editable = $obj;
    $scope.editable.cantidad = parseFloat($scope.editable.cantidad);
    $scope.editable.precio = parseFloat($scope.editable.precio);
    $("#bckimage").css('background-image', 'url('+$scope.editable.foto+')');
    $("#bckimage").css('background-size', 'cover');
    $("#bckimage").css('background-position', 'center');
    $("#editarprod").modal('show');
};
```

Sin embargo al abrir el modal la imagen no sale cargada, y en efecto mi variable editable.foto es una url que si tiene un valor una url valida, cabe mencionar que ya he intentado de la forma document.getElementById, no se si en algo angularjs influya al momento de cargar el modal o que esta pasando pero no me funciona, de hecho ningún parámetro css se le inserta a mi etiqueta, este es la parte de mi html que interesa:

```
<input type="file" name="image_edit" id="image_edit" accept=".jpg, .png, .jpeg">
<label for="image_edit" id="bckimage">
     <span>Selecciona una imagen</span>
     <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i>
</label>
```

Comment: ¿Planeas usar como fondo la imagen seleccionada en el campo? Si la respuesta es afirmativa, entonces lee [esta guía](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications)  para saber cómo usar archivos en aplicaciones web.

Comment: No exactamente, la idea es usar couldinary como gestor para imágenes y luego simplemente acceder a ellas como src, el input es para subir las imágenes desde el ordenador, una vez en el controlador se procesan ya para ser subidas al gestor de couldinary y así simplemente guardar el enlace generado por la api para simplemente usar esa url y mostrarla, el problema es únicamente ese que acabo de plantear, no quiero procesar archivos porque eso ya lo hago, solo quiero que se muestre lo que ya tengo, o saber el porque no se muestra.

Comment: Dentro de la función comprueba que la URL de la imagen es correcta: `console.log($scope.editable.foto);`

Comment: es correcta la url, ya que la uso para mostrarla en un grid antes, pero al pasarla al modal para visualizarla en el formlario simplemente no es capaz de cargarla.

Comment: Abre el Web Dev Tools de Chrome o Firefox, revisa (inspect) el elemento con id `bckimage` y fijate si el CSS que quieres aplicar es correcto. Si hay un error, va a aparecer con un icono de exclamacion.

Comment: no se le aplica ninguno de los estilos hecho, y es raro porque ya había hecho algo similar antes funcionando bien, pero tampoco marca errores

Comment: No se que haga exactamente la funcion `.modal('show')`, si solo cambia el `display` attribute del HTML del modal o si no esta en el DOM y solo cuando ejecutas `.modal()` lo agrega. Si es que recien `#bckimage` se agrega al DOM al llamarlo, `$("#bckimage").css()` no va a encontrar ningun elemento. Puedes probar haciendo `console.log($("#bckimage"))` y ver si jQuery encontro el elemento.